# "window.external.notify" not available in Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone

I am trying to pass data to the Browser's ScriptNotify event in a Windows Phone app. However, `window.external.notify` doesn't work. If I try

```
try {window.external.notify(value);}
catch (e) {alert(e.message);}
```

then it shows me "Object doesn't support this action".

How can I pass data from a Windows Phone browser to the C# app?

Comment: Have you set IsScriptEnabled to true?

Comment: Yes, in the C#, in my Browser Loaded event, I have `Browser.IsScriptEnabled = true;`

Comment: I am using the same code in a tablet version of my app, using a `WebView`. That works. For the phone version, where it doesn't work, I am using `phone:WebBrowser`.

Comment: What is the type of the value?

Comment: `value` is untyped, but it is being passed a string.

Comment: Is exception throwned from C# or Javascript?

Comment: Exception is in Javascript. The Visual Studio debugger does not throw any exceptions, if I dont have the try/catch, it just doesnt do anything. with the try catch it gives me the "Object doesn't support this action message".

Comment: Also, the type of the value doesnt even come into play. I can't even access the notify part yet, `window.external` also gives me "Object doesn't suppor this action".